# Is it impossible to use react dev tools in a Chrome extension dev tools?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-devtools

1. This makes the workflow a lot harder. Is there a way to use react dev tools?
2. I also notice constantly that the extension dev tools take some time to load, like 1 to 2s, and because of that, it misses network requests... is there a way to speed it up? I mean, speed up the development workflow, maybe some way to let the extension use more memory? the first few requests do not show in the network tab, but they are sent to the server.

I'm talking about the dev tools that open when you click on the (service worker) link in the `chrome://extensions/` tab or when you open the **
** and do **right click > inspect**

Answer (score 1):

The standalone version of React Devtools works https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-devtools

Since you can't load the script from localhost you will have to include it in your extension.

To do that, go to http://localhost:8097 (or wherever your react devtools is running), save the JS to a file in your Chrome extension folder and add that with a script tag to your html.

Be sure to remove it before publishing.

Answer (score -1):

> I also notice constantly that the extension dev tools take some time to load, like 1 to 2s, and because of that, it misses network requests... is there a way to speed it up?

You can try to use the Incognito Mode. There will be no extensions used. So, it will not affect your network requests.

Comment: sorry, I will edit my text; I meant to say that I need to speed up my development workflow, and the extension dev tools taking time to load makes it miss network requests in terms of logging them, they don't show up in the network tab, BUT they do happen.